# API call timesout (504) in Postman but redirects (302) in browser

Tags: browser, api, jmeter, postman

I'm trying to test an application with jmeter but the login call (which was working fine last week) is now timing out in both jmeter and postman while still working correctly in the browser.

Comment: The community will require more details to get you a specific answer. My guess is you're getting the 302 because you're being redirected to an "Oops we had an error" or "please sign in first" page. You're likely doing a POST via Postman and a GET via browser.

Comment: no, I'm logging in fine on the website and i am doing POST requests both in the browser and postman, what details should i provide in order to help debugging ?